# Python, Deleting files one by one in multiple directories

Tags: python, file, directory, operating-system

I am facing simple problem, but can't get my head around it. 
I have millions of millions files, in millions of directories I need to delete. 
Windows can't handle it as it's crushing before it even starts deleting. Tries Linux script but that didn't really work.

I decided to write my own program to do that. Idea is simple:

Check if there is a folder in the root path, if there is, go in it, check for folder if it's there go in and that until there is no folders, then delete all the files in that folder then delete that folder, and start again until root directory is empty.

I started trying to use OS library. 
So far I got:

```
import os
rootdir = 'D:/TEST/'
global current_dir
current_dir = rootdir
global dir_counter
dir_counter=0
while (os.listdir(rootdir)[1]):
    print(current_dir)
    if(os.listdir(current_dir)[1]):
        if (os.path.isdir(os.path.join(current_dir,os.listdir(current_dir)[dir_counter+1]))):
            current_dir  = os.path.join(current_dir,os.listdir(current_dir)[dir_counter+1])
            dir_counter = dir_counter+1
```

I was trying just to test if it's going in directories to the end, but unfortunately it goes only one level and stays there.

My folder structure 
TEST1->FOLDER->FOLDER2->FOLDER3
TEST2
TEST3

Comment: Instead of trying to recurse manually, why not use `os.walk` or `glob.rglob`? For that matter, why not just use `shutil` to write the whole thing as a one-liner?

Comment: probably because of my lack of knowledge ;) I will look into your suggestions. 
In my mind it is one-liner, it's simple problem, however it can't  try to list all the files and all the directories, as there is way too many, and that's what's causing all current methods to fail.

Comment: You don’t _need_ to list them all. `os.walk` is a lazy iterator that only lists one directory’s worth of files at a time, not the whole three. And `shutil.rmtree` effectively does the same thing under the covers. It’s close to what you’re trying to write, but it works, and is slightly more efficient, and handles edge cases you didn’t think of (like symlink attacks on Unix), and, best of all, is already written and tested.

Comment: all looks good from what you're saying. I will try to use os.walk for now I can't really understand it, but maybe it's because it's late/early.  Thank you

Comment: Could you help me with os.walk? I can't think of how to make it go to the lowest level subdir. I mean, not in 1 or 2 loops. How can I make it, find directory -> go in -> find directory -> go in -> find directory -> go in -> if no directory delete current one.
it seems like os.walk finds directory and list of sub directories in that directory.

Comment: nevermind, I think i got it. looks great now  live testing. ;) thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Since your need isn't really tied to python, you might consider trying some of the techniques described here:

https://superuser.com/questions/741945/delete-all-files-from-a-folder-and-its-sub-folders?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Best answer because python will be very slow for operations like this

Comment: great, looks good. however tested it and returns some errors in windows powershell. 
But yes, you are also right, it will be slow, and currently i am using linux script on bootable pendrive, i was doing okay but takes ages. 

All because someone thought it will be good idea to keep logs from each test. 
There is more than 2000 Tests a day on each PC. each test creates 70 files and it;s own folder. 
And logs were not deleted for around a year

Comment: @RyanSchaefer No it won’t. The overhead of spending a few nanoseconds interpreting bytecode for each few milliseconds of disk I/O is meaningless.

Comment: I made powershell to work. It takes long time. I mean it's still doing it. and probably won't finish sooner than hour. 
I would still like to try python, just to compare efficiency as I am gonna have to use it more than once.

Comment: @RyanSchaefer Have you actually read that? Because it doesn’t support what you’re saying at all. The blogger’s conclusion is that Python is fast at reading files but slow at processing 16-character `unicode` chunks. So, what about that makes you think it will be slow at deleting files?